# Firemonkey macOS 64 bit app not recognised on osx

Tags: macos, delphi, 64-bit, firemonkey

I have successfully compiled and deployed an app using `macOS 64-bit` as the target platform using Delphi Rio 10.3.2. The app appears to run fine on macOS Mojave, however when I use the `System Report` on the Mac, the app has the `64-bit (intel)` flag set to `No` so I am guessing this app will still be rejected on Catalina when it comes along in October. What do I need to check/change to get the app to be recognised correctly by the `System Report`

To answer Dave,
here is the start of the compiler output

```
*Building AAG.dproj (Debug, OSX64)
brcc32 command line for "AAG.vrc"

  c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\20.0\bin\cgrc.exe -c65001 "AAG.vrc" -foAAG.res 

dccosx64 command line for "AAG.dpr"

  c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\20.0\bin\dccosx64.exe -$O- --no-config -B -Q -AGenerics.Collections=System.Generics.Collections;
  Generics.Defaults=System.Generics.Defaults;WinTypes=Winapi.Windows;WinProcs=Winapi.Windows;DbiTypes=BDE;DbiProcs=BDE;DbiErrs=BDE -DDEBUG 
  -E.\OSX64\Debug -I"c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\20.0\lib\OSX64\debug";"c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\20.0\lib\OSX64\release";
  E:\MyFiles\MyDocuments\Embarcadero\Studio\20.0\Imports;"c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\20.0\Imports";
  C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\20.0\Dcp\OSX64;"c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\20.0\include";"c:\program files 
  (x86)\embarcadero\studio\20.0\redist\OSX64";C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\20.0\Bpl\OSX64;"C:\Program Files (x86)\FastReport FMX 2 
  Professional\Source";"C:\Program Files (x86)\FastReport FMX 2 Professional\FastScript";"E:\MyFiles\MyDocuments\tmssoftware\TMS FMX UI Pack";
  "E:\MyFiles\MyDocuments\tmssoftware\TMS FMX UI Pack\Delphi103Rio\OSX32";"E:\MyFiles\MyDocuments\tmssoftware\TMS FMX UI Pack\XlsAdapter";"C:\Program 
  Files (x86)\FastReport FMX 2 Professional\LibD26OSX64";"C:\Source Files\Rio\AAG\Resource Files\Misc" 
  -LEC:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\20.0\Bpl\OSX64 -LNC:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\20.0\Dcp\OSX64 -NU.\OSX64\Debug 
  -NSSystem;Xml;Data;Datasnap;Web;Soap; -O"c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\20.0\lib\OSX64\release";
  E:\MyFiles\MyDocuments\Embarcadero\Studio\20.0\Imports;"c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\20.0\Imports";
  C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\20.0\Dcp\OSX64;"c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\20.0\include";"c:\program files 
  (x86)\embarcadero\studio\20.0\redist\OSX64";C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\20.0\Bpl\OSX64;"C:\Program Files (x86)\FastReport FMX 2 
  Professional\Source";"C:\Program Files (x86)\FastReport FMX 2 Professional\FastScript";"E:\MyFiles\MyDocuments\tmssoftware\TMS FMX UI Pack";
  "E:\MyFiles\MyDocuments\tmssoftware\TMS FMX UI Pack\Delphi103Rio\OSX32";"E:\MyFiles\MyDocuments\tmssoftware\TMS FMX UI Pack\XlsAdapter";"C:\Program 
  Files (x86)\FastReport FMX 2 Professional\LibD26OSX64";"C:\Source Files\Rio\AAG\Resource Files\Misc" -R"c:\program files 
  (x86)\embarcadero\studio\20.0\lib\OSX64\release";E:\MyFiles\MyDocuments\Embarcadero\Studio\20.0\Imports;"c:\program files 
  (x86)\embarcadero\studio\20.0\Imports";C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\20.0\Dcp\OSX64;"c:\program files 
  (x86)\embarcadero\studio\20.0\include";"c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\20.0\redist\OSX64";
  C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\20.0\Bpl\OSX64;"C:\Program Files (x86)\FastReport FMX 2 Professional\Source";"C:\Program Files 
  (x86)\FastReport FMX 2 Professional\FastScript";"E:\MyFiles\MyDocuments\tmssoftware\TMS FMX UI Pack";"E:\MyFiles\MyDocuments\tmssoftware\TMS FMX UI 
  Pack\Delphi103Rio\OSX32";"E:\MyFiles\MyDocuments\tmssoftware\TMS FMX UI Pack\XlsAdapter";"C:\Program Files (x86)\FastReport FMX 2 
  Professional\LibD26OSX64";"C:\Source Files\Rio\AAG\Resource Files\Misc" -U"c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\20.0\lib\OSX64\debug";
  "c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\20.0\lib\OSX64\release";E:\MyFiles\MyDocuments\Embarcadero\Studio\20.0\Imports;"c:\program files 
  (x86)\embarcadero\studio\20.0\Imports";C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\20.0\Dcp\OSX64;"c:\program files 
  (x86)\embarcadero\studio\20.0\include";"c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\20.0\redist\OSX64";
  C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\20.0\Bpl\OSX64;"C:\Program Files (x86)\FastReport FMX 2 Professional\Source";"C:\Program Files 
  (x86)\FastReport FMX 2 Professional\FastScript";"E:\MyFiles\MyDocuments\tmssoftware\TMS FMX UI Pack";"E:\MyFiles\MyDocuments\tmssoftware\TMS FMX UI 
  Pack\Delphi103Rio\OSX32";"E:\MyFiles\MyDocuments\tmssoftware\TMS FMX UI Pack\XlsAdapter";"C:\Program Files (x86)\FastReport FMX 2 
  Professional\LibD26OSX64";"C:\Source Files\Rio\AAG\Resource Files\Misc" --syslibroot:E:\MyFiles\MyDocuments\Embarcadero\Studio\SDKs\MacOSX10.14.sdk 
  --frameworkpath:E:\MyFiles\MyDocuments\Embarcadero\Studio\SDKs\MacOSX10.14.sdk\System\Library\Frameworks;
  E:\MyFiles\MyDocuments\Embarcadero\Studio\SDKs\MacOSX10.14.sdk\System\Library\PrivateFrameworks -V -VN 
  -NHC:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\20.0\hpp\OSX64 -NO.\OSX64\Debug  AAG.dpr   
[dccosx64 Warning] FMX.TMSCalendar.pas(1923): W1000 Symbol 'Release' is deprecated: 'Support for this method will be removed'
[dccosx64 Warning] FMX.TMSCalendar.pas(2220): W1000 Symbol 'Release' is deprecated: 'Support for this method will be removed'*
```

The first line is obviously referring to a 32 bit compiler, but it is definitely using [dccosx64] which is supposed to be the 64 bit compiler.

Comment: If it's reporting "No", then you have not compiled it for 64-bit.

Comment: I compile mine for 64-bit, it reports "Yes" in System Report. Not sure what else to tell you, except perhaps to make sure there's no instances of your app compiled for 32-bit on your system.

Comment: Good advice David - I completely removed all evidence of the 32 bit version of the App from the Mac, emptied the trash and rebooted - now it is correctly shown as 64bit